# Date serialization issue while upgrading from Wildfly 11 to Wildfly 15

Tags: java, spring, wildfly, java-11, wildfly-15

We have recently migrated from Wildfly 11 to Wildfly 15 and from Java 8 to Java 11 and noticed a change in how Jackson serializes Date objects. We use Jackson v2.9.8 for object serialization and Spring v5.0.9.

Prior to our upgrade, a date object would be serialized in an ISO format e.g. "2019-11-12" but after the upgrade, the date fields started to appear as Timestamps e.g. "1573516800000'. Has anyone else faced this issue before? Is this something that can be configured in `standalone.xml`?

**Wildfly 11 Example**

[image: pre-upgrade date serialization]

**Wildfly 15 Example**

[image: post-upgrade date serialization]

The field is configured as DATE in MySQL

[image]

**Example Entity**

```
public class Entity implements java.io.Serializable {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "value_date")
  private java.sql.Date valueDate;

  public java.sql.Date getValueDate() {
    return valueDate;
  }

  public void setValueDate(java.sql.Date valueDate) {
    this.valueDate = valueDate;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

- We have tried changing the `java.sql.Date` to `java.util.Date` and that has not worked

Comment: Did you try annoating variable with a required format like @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I cannot be sure about your current setup/config, if you configure your `ObjectMapper`, you will probably get the expected behavior:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked like a charm! (with a few mods as we are not using Spring Boot)

Comment: Thanks George! If you could comment on the tweaks you did, I will update my answer to also include those, for future readers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why it is behaving that way but I would change the type of the field to `java.util.Date` and then use the `@Temporal` annotation.

This annotation must be specified for persistent fields or properties of type `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`. It may only be specified for fields or properties of these types.

According to the documentation:

> Temporal data can have DATE, TIME, or TIMESTAMP precision (ie the
>   actual date, only the time, or both). Use the @Temporal annotation to
>   fine tune that.

Your Rest library will then handle conversion between Java Date and ISO. How to configure that depends on the JSON serializer you are using, it is the default format for Date in Jackson

Comment: Thank you for your reply, we have tried changing the date type to `java.util.Date` and that didn't resolve the issue for us which is strange. We've also just tried to add the @Temporal annotation which again had no effect.

Comment: Ok... try adding this annotation above the field in case wildfly is using Jackson `@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", timezone="GMT")`

Answer (score 2):

We had this issue after upgrading our Wildfly application server from 11 to 15, and also our Java from 8 to 11.

Based on [@Sofo Gial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6162023/sofo-gial)'s accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56528881/2869866), the following approach worked for us using Spring 5.0.9.RELEASE / JDK 11 / Wildfly 15.

1) Create a `CustomObjectMapper.java`:

```
package com.mobizio.rest.spring;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        super();
        configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    }

}
```

2) In your context beans configuration XML file add a `<mvc:message-converters>` entry between the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` tags, and create a bean of the `CustomObjectMapper`:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
...
<mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
    </bean>
</mvc:message-converters>
...
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="com.mobizio.rest.spring.CustomObjectMapper" />
```